# How to deploy website?

Tags: ubuntu, web

I have all of the code (HTML/CSS, etc.) for my website in a folder. I also have an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean and a domain.

How do I deploy my website?

Answer (score 0):

Digital ocean recommends  to use any SSH based tools like SFTP or SCP for deployment and only use FTP if not possible otherwise

How To Launch Your Site on a New Ubuntu 14.04 Server with LAMP, SFTP, and DNS

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-launch-your-site-on-a-new-ubuntu-14-04-server-with-lamp-sftp-and-dns

https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/